CMake: Automaticaly update compilation database with compdb
we are using CMake with CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS to generate a compilation database that is used for our IDEs and code analysis.
Some header-only libraries do not work as expected though. 
Since the compilation database does not include header files we tried adding them with compdb.
This does work but is an extra step that I would like to avoid. 
Especially since the CMake can be triggered directly or through make/ninja on change 
and running compdb takes some time (just triggering it every time is really expensive).
The latest idea was to use cmake_language(DEFER) to add a post-configuration-hook. 
This seems to still be too early as the updated compile_commands.json is overwritten again before cmake finishes.
cmake_language(DEFER DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} CALL _compdb_update_compilation_database())

Is there

either a possibility to run compdb reliably after the compilation database was written from within CMAKE
or another way to add header files to the compilation database during configuration time?


I do not see a great way to do it, and I believe no, there is no "hook" to place after the compilation database was created. I would use cmake for depenedncy add_custom_command(DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json COMMAND compdb .... OUTPUTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_commands.json) and generate the source dir compile commands only if binary dir compile commands has changed.

To update compile_commands.json with headers, use add_custom_command in CMake. This not perfect, but helps:
# CMakeLists.txt

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
project(MyProject)

set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)

# Your usual CMake setup
add_executable(MyExecutable main.cpp)

# Custom command to run compdb after compile_commands.json generated
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    COMMAND compdb -p ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} list > ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_commands.json
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/compile_commands.json
)

# Add a target to make sure the custom command runs
add_custom_target(UpdateCompileCommands ALL
    DEPENDS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/compile_commands.json
)

add_dependencies(MyExecutable UpdateCompileCommands)

This way, compdb run after compile_commands.json generated, adding headers without extra step. Not perfect, but work.

Thank you for your contribution.
Unfortunately this needs to execute the target, so it's part of the build and not the configuration, meaning this is executed by either make or ninja and not as part of running make.
